# How to convert dataframe to trianing data for spacy?

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a data frame `df` which needs to be converted into spacy's training data format.

my dataframe `df` is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['LSCS', 'SVD', 'URTI']})
df['start'] = 0
df['end'] = df['Names'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

I need to convert above `df`  to following list format which will be used to train spacy NER model.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("LSCS", {"entities": [(0, 4, "ENTITY")]}),
    ("SVD", {"entities": [(0, 3, "ENTITY")]}),
    ("URTI", {"entities": [(0, 4, "ENTITY")]}),]
```

I have tried the following code, but could not accomplish the required output

```
List =  []
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    my_list = [rows.start, rows.end]
    List.append(my_list)
    my_list.append('entity')
print(List)

List_tuple  = [tuple(l) for l in List]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `apply` then `series.tolist()`

```
df['Names'].apply(lambda x: (x,{'entries':[(0,len(x),'ENTITY')]})).tolist()
```

---

```
[('LSCS', {'entries': [(0, 4, 'ENTITY')]}),
 ('SVD', {'entries': [(0, 3, 'ENTITY')]}),
 ('URTI', {'entries': [(0, 4, 'ENTITY')]})]
```